# Is it acceptable to not include all function declarations in the header to create a "private namespace"?

Tags: c++, namespaces, private

I've been writing some code for a while now. I've been using namespaces to separate a few parts of code to make the code more readable. However, I ran into a problem where I wanted to make something in that private. Here's what I found works:

```
//foobar.h
namespace foo_bar {
  //Other items here...
}
```

```
//foobar.cpp
namespace foo_bar {
  //Other items here...
  void foo_barz() {..
    //Faked private method!
  }
}
```

It compiled fine. Is there any negative to using this method? I think a class might have been a better choice for this, but using a namespace, at the time, seemed like a simpler solution because it was all one project. Is there a more "conventional" way to do this? Is this likely to cause other issues down the road? What might some issues with this be?

**EDIT:** I guess I wasn't clear what I did. What I did was this: I didn't include the function prototype in the header file, so when included, the header file makes the code which the file was included into think that the function doesn't exist.

Comment: The symbol will still be accessible outside the TU, this is what [unnamed namespaces](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Unnamed_namespaces) are for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make `foo_barz` really "private" (i.e. not have its name accessible from other units), place it in an anonymous namespace, not `foo_bar`:

```
// foobar.cpp

namespace   /* stuff in here is only visible within this unit */
{ 
    void foo_barz() { ...
}
```

If you wanted to declare that function before defining it, you could add:

```
namespace 
{
    void foo_barz();
}
```

because multiple unnamed namespaces in the same unit actually all refer to the same unnamed namespace.

Another way to achieve the same thing is to declare the function as static:

```
static void foo_barz() { ...
```

which may be done inside or outside of a namespace. Some people disapprove of this option (for reasons that are not clear to me).

Comment: For the anonymous namespace, how would I write the function prototype/reference to use `foo_barz`? Also, for the static function, I still not include this in the header file?

Comment: Only include things in the header file if you intend them to be used from other units. (So, don't do it in this case).  Updated post to include function prototype, which is only necessary if you can't put the function definition before its call

Comment: RE the `static` vs unnamed `namespace` debate I just find it easier to read definitions wrapped in a namespace rather than have `static` in front of everything.